# What exactly is happening in this parsing-function?

Tags: c, parsing, pointers

While looking for a way to parse the input line and seperate it in some arguments in C, I found this (from here [example for `fork()`](http://www.csl.mtu.edu/cs4411.ck/www/NOTES/process/fork/exec.html)).
I (at least think) do understand most of it, but I really have problems in understanding why `*arguments++ = token;` works. If I'm right, `arguments` should be a pointer to an array of pointers. And `token` a pointer to the input-string. So when the while-loop has it's very first iteration, it skips the first while-loop, because `token` is not pointing at any whitespaces.

And now comes the part which confuses me: `arguments` gets the address `token` is pointing to and is then incremented. Fine. **But doesn't that mean, that the first pointer in this array of pointers is now pointing to the complete string `"abc def ghi"`?**

On the given website is a picture and I'm always thinking, that `"abc def ghi"` must be on position 0, but only `abc` is (which is fine and totally is what I want). **How did the code make it so that `arguments[0]` contains `"abc"`, and not `"abc def ghi"` ?**

What do I miss or got wrong? Can someone clear me up? The confusing code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h`enter code here`>

void parse_cmd(char *token, char **arguments)
{
    while (*token != '\0') {
        while (*token == ' ' || *token == '\0' || *token == '\n')
                *token++ = '\0'; 
        /* What exactly is happening here and why does it work? */
        *arguments++ = token;
        while (*token != ' ' && *token != '\0' && *token != '\n'){
            token++;
        }
    }               
    *arguments = '\0';
}

int  main(void)
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    char *arguments[64];
    char input[] = "abc def ghi"; 

    parse_cmd(input, arguments);

    while(arguments[i] != '\0'){
        while (arguments[i][j] != '\0'){
            printf("%c", arguments[i][j]);
            j++;
        }
        puts("");
        j = 0;
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This can be answered very quickly in a debugger

Comment: The question was buried in a bunch of prose, but never truly unclear. I have reformatted the original question to make it stand out, and repeated it in paragraph below it, as well as removed the red-herring in the question title.

Comment: @jxh thx for editing - you're highlighted text were the two points that bothered me, escpecially the last one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You asked:

> ... And now comes the part which confuses me: `arguments` gets the address `token` is pointing to and is then incremented. Fine. But doesn't that mean, that the first pointer in this array of pointers is now pointing to the complete string `"abc def ghi"`?

You missed what the loop above `*arguments++ = token;` is doing, which is to modify the whitespace it sees into a string terminating `'\0'`.

```
    while (*token == ' ' || *token == '\0' || *token == '\n')
            *token++ = '\0';
    *arguments++ = token;
```

The termination gets assigned on the next iteration of the outer loop.

Comment: Thx! I didn't see the wood for the trees and didn't realize the termination AFTER *token gets advanced. :o) Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The expression

```
*arguments++ = token;
```

is parsed as

```
*(arguments++) = token;
```

and is roughly equivalent to

```
*arguments = token; // asign value of 'token' to the object pointed to by 'arguments'
arguments++;        // advance 'arguments' to point to next object
```

Comment: Thx. Didn't answer exactly my question (my fault, I was a bit unprecise) but helped me anyway to improve my understanding for pointers :o).

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote

```
void parse_cmd(char *token, char **arguments)
```

to

```
void parse_cmd(char *token, char **args)
```

for the sake of explaining.

In the main function you have

```
char *arguments[64]; //64 member array of pointers to char
```

In short, in the above step you have 64 pointers.

When you call :

```
     parse_cmd(      input,    arguments);
                       ^            ^
                       |            |  args points to 
         token points  |            |  arguments[0] which indeed is a 
         to &input[0]  |            |  pointer to char. Since args has
                       |            |  type char*, args++ can be used 
                       |            |  access the next element in 
                       |            |  arguments[] ie arguments[1] to [64]
                       v            v
void parse_cmd(char *token, char **args)
```

Since args has type `char*`, `args++` can be used access the next element in `arguments[]`, ie `arguments[1]`. When you do.

```
*args++ = token; // ++ done first,then *
```

Since the operation is postfix current value of args( ie `arguments[0]`) is used for the dereferencing operation(ie *) before it is incremented(ie now args points to `arguments[1]`). But `arguments[0]` itself is a pointer to char as declared in main. Adding the right hand side, you get

```
arguments[0]=token;//remember arguments[0] in main
```

in the first step. This assigns `arguments[0]` to token which is another pointer to char.

Comment: Thanks for this nice explanation - helped me to improve my understanding of pointers. :o)